# How to get the directory of the package the file is in, not the current working directory

Tags: go

I'm making a package to make API calls to a service.

I have a test package that I use just to test the API calls and test the functions of the main package which I just `include` the other package into.

In my main package that I'm working on I have

`ioutil.ReadFile(filepath.Abs("Filename.pub"))`

Which is ok, but when I call it from my test package e.g.

`/Users/####/gocode/src/github.com/testfolder go run main.go`

it tells me

`panic: open /Users/####/gocode/src/github.com/testfolder/public.pub: no such file or directory`

The problem is, is it is looking for `public.pub` inside of `testfolder` instead of `github.com/apipackage/` which is where it is.

Just to clarify this mess of words:

The API Package has a function that reads from the same directory

But because I'm including the API package and Testfolder is the CWD when I `go run main.go` it is instead trying to get it from the `testfolder` instead even though the main.go doesn't have the function and is just including it.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

[runtime.Caller](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Caller) is what you want I believe.

Here is a demonstration :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "path"
)

func main() {
    _, filename, _, ok := runtime.Caller(0)
    if !ok {
        panic("No caller information")
    }
    fmt.Printf("Filename : %q, Dir : %q\n", filename, path.Dir(filename))
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/vVa2q-Er6D

Comment: When I ran a quick test of this the current file was in `runtime.Caller(3)` when I was debugging a test so `(0)` is not guaranteed to be the value you want.

Comment: @jcollum you only need to increase this number if you wrapped the `runtime.Caller` call in functions which are not in the dir you want.

Typically if you made a helper function out of this snippet, you'd replace 0 by 1

Comment: I think that there's no way to really determine which level of runtime.Caller you need at runtime. Better to not rely on it if you can.

Comment: You can, even statically. Here is what the documentation says: `The argument skip is the number of stack frames to ascend, with 0 identifying the caller of Caller.`

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't address my comment. How do you know how many frames to skip? You can't, really, so it's better to not rely on it if you can.

Comment: And really in a compiled language you should probably get over the notion of loading files from a relative path -- that path could be pointing anywhere in the OS. If you really need that file as part of your regular operations it should be packed in to the binary. If it's an input argument, ok cool, try to load it.

Comment: It's mostly useful in tests. Once compiled, the notion of "path of the source file" is indeed useless.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Go 1.16, you can use the [embed](https://pkg.go.dev/embed) package. This allows you to embed the files in the running go program. The referenced file needs to be at or below the embedding file. In your case, the structure would look as follows:

```
-- apipackage
  \- public.pub
  \- apipackage.go
-- testfolder
  \- main.go
```

You can reference the file using a go directive

```
// apipackage.go
package apipackage

import (
  "embed"
)

//go:embed public.pub
var content embed.FS

func GetText() string {
  text, _ := content.ReadFile("public.pub")
  return text
}
```

This program will run successfully regardless of where the program is executed.

Comment: what do u mean by when u said that referenced file should be below the embedding file

Comment: @needhelp I meant that the file public.pub needs to be in the same directory (or a nested directory) as apipackage.go. Let me know if that helps.