# How to get path of imported package

Tags: go, path

I'm having difficulty when trying to get path of imported package. When I print result of `os.Getwd()` inside imported package, it's showing same path like on `main` package.

This what I did.

#### Project structure

[image]

#### lib/lib.go

```
package lib

import "os"
import "fmt"

func init() {
    dir, _ := os.Getwd()
    fmt.Println("lib.init() :", dir)
}

func GetPath() {
    dir, _ := os.Getwd()
    fmt.Println("lib.GetPath() :", dir)
}
```

#### main.go

```
package main

import "os"
import "fmt"
import "test-import/lib"

func main() {
    dir, _ := os.Getwd()
    fmt.Println("main :", dir)
    lib.GetPath()
}
```

#### Result

```
lib.init() : /Users/novalagung/Documents/go/src/test-import
main : /Users/novalagung/Documents/go/src/test-import
lib.GetPath() : /Users/novalagung/Documents/go/src/test-import
```

The result of `os.Getwd()` from `lib/lib.go` is still same path like on main. What I want is the real path of the package which is `/Users/novalagung/Documents/go/src/test-import/lib/`

What should I do? Is it possible?

Comment: `os.Getwd` returns a rooted path name corresponding to the current directory at runtime. It does no matter with the source path which only work in compile-time. Maybe tell us what problem you need resolving.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32163425/golang-how-to-get-the-directory-of-the-package-the-file-is-in-not-the-current-w.

Comment: @JiangYD "Maybe tell us what problem you need resolving", basically I create some application which contains sub applications inside which have different package each other. If I can get the name of the subfolder, it'll make me easier to maintain the routes

Comment: @JiangYD nevermind, david answer solve my problem

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you can get a reference to something in the package, you can use reflect to get the import path.

Here's an example on [Play](https://play.golang.org/p/Ug3RkqLtBT):

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    var b bytes.Buffer
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(b).PkgPath())
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`PkgPath()` only can retrieve the package path for non-pointer

```golang
// If the type was predeclared (string, error) or not defined (*T, struct{},
// []int, or A where A is an alias for a non-defined type), the package path
// will be the empty string.
func packageName(v interface{}) string {
    if v == nil {
        return ""
    }

    val := reflect.ValueOf(v)
    if val.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        return val.Elem().Type().PkgPath()
    }
    return val.Type().PkgPath()
}
```