# How to determine directory of package's source files

Tags: go

I have a package in a repo that has static files in it.

```
myPackage
static/sample.json
main.go
```

`main.go` uses `os.Open('static/sample.json")` and processes the file

Then I have another repo that consumes mypackage by importing it. The problem is that it is looking for the json file in this new repo.  I tried to put the full path github.com/username/mypackage/static/sample.json but it still can't be found. Is there a way I can keep the files in the other package?

Comment: Note that you should _not do this_!! It's common (in fact, probably the normal case), that your compiled code doesn't run on the same machine as your source files. So `runtime`'s output may have nothing to do with the system that is executing the code. Proper practice is instead to pass the location to your static files as configuration, which can be configured per-installation.

Answer (score -1):

From this question [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32163888/1202542)

```
_, filename, _, ok := runtime.Caller(0)

if !ok {
    panic("no caller information")
}

os.Open(path.Dir(filename) + '/static/sample.json")
```

did the trick.